# Optional regex complication

Tags: regex, perl

I have this input:

```
stuff (2+13:02)
more stuff (20:32)
more more stuff (8+23:00)
```

The `2+` is optional and stands for a completely different value, so I wrote this regex:

> /((?:(\d)?+?)(\d+:\d+))/g

The `$1` should always be the number BEFORE the `+` and group the rest of the digits and `:` in `$2` but that doesn't always happen.  In the example of `(20:32)`, `$1` will be `2` and `$2` will be `0:32`. How can I make `$1` `undef` and `$2 = 20:32` ?

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try you moving the `?` to after the group you want to be optional. Also you usually need to escape the `+` if want to match a literal `+`:

```
/(?:(\d)\+)?(\d+:\d+)/g
```

This will match a:

- An optional, non-captured group of:

  - A single digit, captured in group 1
  - A literal `+`
- One or more digits, followed by by a `:`, followed by one or more digits, captured in group 2